# join data.table after group by

Tags: r, data.table

I have a fairly simple question that I could not find a suitable answer here. I have the following `data.table`, which I want to create a indicator variable equal to 1 if the group `ID` has an observation with a specific value, in this case, `13`:

```
DT = data.table(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), A = c(13, 1, 13, 11, 12, 12))

DT
   ID  A
1:  1 13
2:  1  1
3:  2 13
4:  3 11
5:  3 12
6:  3 12
```

My desired result, which is a simple split-apply-combine in dplyr lingo, would be:

```
DT
   ID  A B
1:  1 13 1
2:  1  1 1
3:  2 13 1
4:  3 11 0
5:  3 12 0
6:  3 12 0
```

My idea was to do something along the lines of `DT[A == 13, B := 1][, B := max(B, na.rm=TRUE), by='ID']`, and it kind of works but results in some `-Inf` values for groups with no observations equal to 13. Is there a better way to do this?

In a split-apply-combine framework, I would start with `DT[A == 13, B := 1, by='ID']`, then do a LEFT JOIN, but want to do it the `data.table` way as much as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a group by 'ID' to assign (`:=`) if there are `any` value in 'A' that is equal to 13

```
library(data.table)
DT[,  B := +(any(A == 13)), ID]
```

Or with `%in%`

```
DT[, B := +(13 %in% A), ID]
DT
#   ID  A B
#1:  1 13 1
#2:  1  1 1
#3:  2 13 1
#4:  3 11 0
#5:  3 12 0
#6:  3 12 0
```